# Too many players on the basketball court

Tags: rules, basketball

After making substitutions, we accidentally had 6 players on the court (5th grade girls).  I called a timeout when I saw it (after maybe 5 seconds elapsed), and was granted the timeout. The refs did not realize we had 6 players until after allowing me the timeout when somebody from the stands yelled out.

I was then given a technical and still charged me with the timeout. Should I still have been assessed the technical foul?  Should I still have been charged the Timeout? While I acknowledge this was a fault on my part, it seems unfair that I got charged with *both* the technical and the timeout.

Comment: What rules are you playing under? NFHS?

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be pinged for the obvious technical breach simply because you were quicker to see it?

Comment: A charge is over once the player has broken physical contact and their opponent has hit the ground. That doesn't mean that the referees can't call the infraction.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming NFHS, Rule 10-1 says it's a Team Technical, which indirectly affects the coach; the timeout doesn't negate that it happened, so technically the ref's were correct in the administration. They should have still allowed you the timeout before the free-throws were administered.

Now, personally, as a former official, I think it was tacky that they enforced it. I called a lot of Jr. High boys and girls and half the time the coaches were trying to teach the kids how to play. Rule 3-3-3 says the ref's are to administer the substitutions, so it's their fault for allowing it to happen. If you were in a huddle and broke with 6, and then called a timeout before the ball went into play, I think they could have let it slide.

But, technically, they were correct.